# listview checkbox selected vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, checkbox, selected

I have a listview with a checkbox on it but when I click the checkbox on the listview item, the item doesn't get selected. I want the listview item to be selected whenever I click the checkbox on the listview.

Comment: Did you have a programming question? See [Ask]

Comment: yes..sorry I didn't interpret clearly...what I'm asking is how to set the listview item whenever its checkbox is check or unchecked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will set the selected item to the row of your selected checkbox:

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemCheck
     ListView1.Items(e.Index).Selected = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Ive already set the FullRowSelect property to True and it doesn't select the full row of the item whenever I check the checkbox.

Comment: can you provide more details of your listview?

Comment: The properties Ive set to my listview are  Checkboxes-True  FullRowSelect-True  HideSelection-False  MultiSelect-False

Comment: try the code I answered. I tested it in my computer.